# assign output of command to variable in bash script run by root cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have been trying to write a script that will backup my minecraft server but only run if I am not actively on the server.  The way i am trying to do this is by parsing the output of top and grepping the process name and getting the CPU usage.  When I am not on the server the usage is usually less than 10.  The server is run as a service so in order to bring it down before the backup and to bring it back up I need to use `systemctl stop` and `systemctl start` in so it need to be run as root.  This is the script I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin"

CPU=`/usr/bin/top -b n1 | /usr/bin/grep bedrock_server | /usr/bin/awk '{ print $9 }' | /usr/bin/cut -d . -f 1`

DATE=`date '+\%m-\%d'`
dirname="/home/brandon/bedrock-backups/$DATE"
if [ "$CPU" -lt 20 ];
    then
        systemctl stop bedrock-server.service && \
        mkdir -p $dirname && chown brandon $dirname && chmod 777 $dirname && \
        cd /home/brandon && \
        tar -czf $dirname/bedrock-backup.tar bedrock/ && \
        chown brandon $dirname/bedrock-backup.tar && chmod 777 $dirname/bedrock-backup.tar && \
        echo "Backup Completed Successfully"  && \
        systemctl start bedrock-server.service
    else
        echo "Backup terminated due to server activity" && \
        exit
fi
```

The issue seems to be that the output of the top command and all the subsequent parsing does not get assigned to CPU so the script errors out at `if [ "$CPU" -lt 20 ]` with the error `integer expression expected`.  I tried to run the script in cron's env by adding the line `env > ~/cronenv` to root's crontab and have it run once then use `` env - `cat ~/cronenv`  /bin/sh `` to get into crons environment.  I run

```
CPU=`top -b n1 | grep bedrock_server | awk '{ print $9 }' | cut -d . -f 1`
```

and it works.  I tried again as a cron job and I get the same error.  Then I read that full paths to commands should be used inside cron so I added `/usr/bin` to the commands as seen above.

I've tried using `#!/bin/sh` as well as `#!/bin/bash` for the shebang.  The crontab entry is as follows :

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin"
27 22 * * * /bin/bash /home/brandon/bin/scripts/backup-bedrock
#* * * * * env > ~/cronenv
```

I can even run the full script in the cronenv but not scheduled as a cron job.

I do not know what else to try or what I am doing wrong, hoping someone can help me.

Thanks!

Also this is on Ubuntu 20.04 if that matters

Comment: What does the variable CPU contain before the comparison?

Comment: It's supposed to contain the CPU usage of the bedrock_server process without the decimal.  When I run it outside of the cron job it works, but whenever I run it in the cronjob it doesn't seem to get populated with anything.

I didnt it would be different in the cronjob I guess I assumed if it worked when I run it under the cron environment that it would work in the cronjob.  I will test real quick with a comma and see.

Comment: Same error `/home/brandon/bin/scripts/backup-bedrock: line 14: [: : integer expression expected`

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: That definitely does help  output was 
```
+ PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
++ /usr/bin/grep bedrock_server
++ /usr/bin/top -b n1
++ /usr/bin/awk '{ print $9 }'
++ /usr/bin/cut -d , -f 1
+ CPU=
+ echo
++ date '+\%m-\%d'
+ DATE='\05-\16'
+ dirname='/home/brandon/bedrock-backups/\05-\16'
+ '[' '' -lt 20 ']'
+ echo 'Backup terminated due to server activity'
+ exit
```
that gives me a starting point to figure this out instead of blindly trying different things.  Thanks for the assist

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Found out that top actually truncated bedrock_server to bedrock+, I changed the grep to bedrock and change the delimiter back to . and it worked!  Thanks again for your help! @Cyrus